# How can I find and remove elements that have a specific pattern from a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list that is something like this:

```
output=['Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on', '/dev/mapper/vg00-lvol_root', '                      976M  356M  570M  39% /', 'tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm', '/dev/mapper/vg00-lvol_apps', '                       20G  6.1G   13G  33% /apps', '/dev/sda1             976M   63M  863M   7% /boot', '/dev/mapper/vg00-lvol_data'.....]
```

I want to remove all the elements that has the format `"/dev/mapper/...."`.
E.g. here `list[1]='/dev/mapper/vg00-lvol_root'`. I tried using the index to remove(since in this case the odd no is occupied by the pattern. But that's not the case always). I then tried the logic of converting the elements to strings and then use regex to find the pattern. I thought of running a for loop to extract the list elements to individual strings(all that was complicated). I'm sure there must be an easier way to solve this

Comment: Can you please format your question a bit better so it is easier to read? Also, it would help to see your code attempt at this to help further clarify your difficulties. Finally, pro-tip, don't use `list` to define your *list* since it shadows the built-in `list`.

Comment: @J.Paul don't just keep it in mind; use the [edit] link to [edit] it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l=['Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on', '/dev/mapper/vg00-lvol_root', ' 976M 356M 570M 39% /', 'tmpfs 1.9G 0 1.9G 0% /dev/shm', '/dev/mapper/vg00-lvol_apps', ' 20G 6.1G 13G 33% /apps', '/dev/sda1 976M 63M 863M 7% /boot', '/dev/mapper/vg00-lvol_data']

filtered = [ x for x in l if "/dev/mapper/" not in x ]

print(filtered)
```

Output:

> ['Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on', ' 976M 356M 570M 39%
>   /', 'tmpfs 1.9G 0 1.9G 0% /dev/shm', ' 20G 6.1G 13G 33% /apps',
>   '/dev/sda1 976M 63M 863M 7% /boot']

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple strings need to be check, you may need this.

```
regex=re.compile('^/dev/mapper|^/usr/a')
filtered_list = [s for s in my_list if not re.match(regex, s)]
```